# Vitest does not recognise vuetify custom components

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, custom-component, vitest

I have a vue3 app tested in vitest. I am using vuetify for components in the app. Unfortunately, vuetify components e.g. `<v-btn>`, `<v-icon>`, are not recognised by vitest.

[In the console, I get errors like the one in the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZAw.png)

How can I tell vitest to treat them as vuetify components?

BTW I also use typescript

Comment: Have you solved this yet?